# How to use Realm asObservable with RxJava's concat() operator?

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I'm trying to use Realm with RxJava and Retrofit in a way DanLew described [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) concating input from realm and retrofit but it gets stuck if I adding realm into the chain

```
Observable.concat(countryStorage.restoreAsObservable(),
              networkService.api()
                  .getCountries()
                  .doOnNext(countryStorage::save))
              .first()
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(//never reaching here)
```

storage

```
 @Override public Observable<List<Country>> restoreAsObservable() {
        Realm realm = realmProvider.get();
        return realm.where(Country.class)
            .findAll()
            .asObservable()
            .map(countries -> return realm.copyFromRealm(countries))
            .first(countries -> return !countries.isEmpty())
            .doOnCompleted(realm::close());
      }
```

It seems that this could happen that observable is hot from Realm, but nothing about it in the docs and how I suppose to compose Realm with other observables?

**UPDATE:**
It turns to be that it works fine in old way. The question still remain about new api.

```
return Observable.just(
        realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Country.class).findAll()))
        .filter(countries -> !countries.isEmpty())
        .doOnCompleted(realm::close);
```

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1998 Same question on github. See progress there.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: `doOnCompleted` will never be called

Comment: Are you sure, you have some countries in your Realm database? If not, chain remain stuck at line `.first(countries -> return !countries.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `countryStorage.restoreAsObservable()` never completes and if you read [concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) doc, it explicitly states that:

> Concat waits to subscribe to each additional Observable that you pass to it until the previous Observable completes.

Instead you can just do something like:

```
    countryStorage.restoreAsObservable()
          .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
              networkService.api()
                  .getCountries()
                  .subscribe(countryStorage::save)
          })
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(//do smth)
```